# fgets in a while loop

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fgets

The following code is giving me a segmentation fault at the fgets call in the while loop (it does not reach the printf statement inside the while loop for debugging).

I have shown here the main (taking args from the command line) and the start of function partOne.

Any ideas?

```
int main(int lLen, char *fileName)
{
    Word* allWords = (Word*)malloc(sizeof(Word));
    int numwords = 0;

    /*Create char*'s for fileName.out and fileName.words*/
    char *newName = malloc(sizeof(char)*50);
    char *newName2 = malloc(sizeof(char)*50);

    FILE* inputFile = fopen(fileName, "r+"); /*open file for reading*/

    partOne(lLen, numwords, fileName, allWords, inputFile, newName);
    partB(numwords, fileName, allWords, newName2);

    return 0;
}

/*Function partOne reads in words from a file and tidies them up into a neatly-formatted paragraph based on passed line length*/
int partOne(int lLen, int numwords, char *fileName, Word *allWords, FILE* inputFile, char *newName)
{
    char *insPtr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*50); /*Make insPtr for allWords[pos].word to point to*/
    char *insPtr2 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*50); /*Make insPtr for allWords[pos].word to point to*/
    char *outputLine = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100); /*Initialize the output line to nothing*/
    char *currentWord = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*50); /*Initialize current word to nothing*/
    int pos = 0; /*Current position for inserting into array*/
    FILE* outputFile = fopen(newName, "w+");

    newName = strcat(fileName, ".out"); /*Add extension to fileName*/

printf("In partOne\n");
    while(fgets(outputLine, 100, inputFile) != NULL) /*Get line*/
    {
        int cCount = 0; /*Number of characters in current line*/
        int flag = 0; /*Break for repetition*/
        int i = 0; /*Counter for repetition*/

printf("Top of while\npos=%d cCount=%d\n", pos, cCount);
        /*If not the first line, increment position*/
        if(pos > 0)
        {
            pos++;
        }
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: You invented your own parameters for `main`?  It's either **filename or *filename[]), preferable neither.  Most us get along with argc and argv.

Comment: Are you sure inputFile is opened at the fgets?

Comment: Why `malloc` `char` arrays?  Just use `char insPtr[50]`, etc.

Comment: You may be interested in terminating those dynamic allocations prior to invoking something that *requires* prior-termination (like `strcat`). Or use the sledge-hammer-to-kill-a-fly approach and use `calloc` instead.

Comment: I'm sure `inputFile` is not opened at the `fgets`, due to the invalid signature of `main`

Comment: Right on - I got the main args changed and it's opening.  Thanks all.